# How do I only show one element on click within an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
.div(ng-repeat='x in xs')
    {{x}}
  .title-div(ng-click='showIt = ! showIt')
  .display-div(ng-show='showIt')
    .second-repeat(ng-repeat='b in bs')
       .display-contents(ng-if='x == b.x')
         {{b.name}}
```

---

html is template for jade / haml, if you are not familiar

---

So, with this code above, I can toggle the ng-show when I click on the title-div. However, I want to only be able to have one display-div show at a time within the ng-repeat. When I click a corresponding title the display-div shows, then the others are hidden.

I know how I would do this in Jquery, but I'm a bit lost as the proper way to do this in angular. Directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is not jQuery hence you should not think from the perspective of UI. Show this element and hide another element. Think from the model perspective.

One of the solution has been outlined by @atinder which involved extending the model (`x`). The other option is to define a variable like `activeItem` on scope and set it whenever an item is clicked on UI.

```
.div(ng-repeat='x in xs')
  .title-div(ng-click='setActive(x)')
  .display-div(ng-show='activeItem==x')
```

On scope you need to do

```
$scope.setActive=function(item) {
   $scope.activeItem=item;
}
```

Remember you cannot do `activeItem=x` on view as ng-repeat creates a new scope.

Comment: Thx. This seems solid. And, for what I asked, I think is the best answer. care to drop a hint on how to hide the display-div on click if its x is the activeItem. 'Toggle an open item back to closed'. I definitely need to work on thinking from the model perspective.

Comment: If activeItem has value and the call again gets the active item, then set the activeitem to null. I am not sure I am answering your query correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For booleans in ng directives you can do object comparisons

In scope once data arrives set :

```
$scope.state={xActive : $scope.xs[0]};
```

Then you can  set xActive to the current object within `ng-click`and check for it in `ng-show`

```
.div(ng-repeat='x in xs')
  .title-div(ng-click='state.xActive = x')
  .display-div(ng-show='state.xActive == x')
```

Other use cases for object comparisons are directives like `ng-class`, `'ng-if` etc:

```
<div ng-class="{'blue-class': state.xActive == x}">
```

Comment: this was really good. The only reason I didn't choose it, is that that index [0] is always open on the initial page load.

Comment: wasn't clear what expected behavior was...not difficult to change. Also easier to show how to activate from the start than come back later with the opposite problem of "I want one open"

Answer (score 0):

one solution could be

```
.div(ng-repeat='x in xs')
  .title-div(ng-click='x.showIt = ! showIt')
  .display-div(ng-show='x.showIt')
```

make sure showIt is there on x object.

Comment: problem here is it won't toggle on the current one when another one is clicked

Comment: not sure that helps, the show is still bound to instance of x and nothing to change showIt